# How to use limitTo filter only when all data will be grabbed from firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-filter

I want to show only 3 most recent reviews (every review have "id" value), but limitTo and orderBy filters doesn't work here correctly. I guess it's because when filter runs there is not data from firebase yet.

How to apply these filter only when categories.$loaded() == true? I tried with custom filters but didn't manage to do it correctly...

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
        <div ng-repeat="vendor in category.vendors">
            <div ng-repeat="review in vendor.reviews | orderBy: -id | limitTo:3">
                <img src="img/placeholder-avatar.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="right-content">
                    <h4>{{ vendor.name }}</h4>
                    <div class="stars"></div>
                    <span class="category"> {{ category.name }} </span>
                    <p> {{ review.body | limitTo:100 }}{{ review.body.length < 100 ? '' : '...'}} </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In controller I have only:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $firebaseObject) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://scorching-torch-1679.firebaseio.com");
  $scope.categories = $firebaseObject(ref);
});
```

My firebase structure (here I'm trying to get to the reviews, that are assigned to vendors inside categories):

[image]

Comment: html code has nothing wrong, post the controller's code

Comment: you can try adding ng-if on first ng-repeat that test categories.$loaded but i don't think this is the problem. Exactly which is the result? It render all the results ignoring filters?

Comment: Yes indeed, it displays all reviews. Maybe you are right, that this is not the problem, adding ng-if as you said doesn't change anything - it still loads all reviews. Only filter on review.body works correctly.

Comment: `orderBy` filter ask for a string argument, try change to `orderBy:'-id'`

Comment: Why do you want to first download all data from the server and then filter on things that the user didn't specify? It's more efficient to send the query to the Firebase server and let that handle what it can: `$scope.categories = $firebaseArray(ref.orderByChild('body_length').endAt(100).limitToFirst(100))`. You'll need to add a `body_length` property that you keep up to date. But the benefit is that your data downloads will be a lot smaller.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help. I know I have to optimalize my code. 

I found that limitTo didn't work, because in nested ng-repeat limitTo just doesn't work, it works only in outer ng-repeat.

Comment: Rather than using $loaded(), which is almost always the wrong answer for real-time data, one should filter by [using $extend and tapping into the $$added method](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/bee266e31aa60cb0eed6). Even better would be to simply call limitToFirst() or limitToLast() on `ref` and [do the limit at the server](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries).

Answer (score 1):

This will help to load this after categories.$loaded() == true:

```
 <div ng-if="categories.$loaded()">
     <div ng-repeat="category in categories">
       <div ng-repeat="vendor in category.vendors">
        <div ng-repeat="review in vendor.reviews | orderBy: -id | limitTo:3">
            <img src="img/placeholder-avatar.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="right-content">
                <h4>{{ vendor.name }}</h4>
                <div class="stars"></div>
                <span class="category"> {{ category.name }} </span>
                <p> {{ review.body | limitTo:100 }}{{ review.body.length < 100 ? '' : '...'}} </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I don't think there is the problem. If you want to filter after categories.$loaded() == true, make it in your own filter:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function(){ 
       function myFilter(elms, filters) {
            if(categories.$loaded()) {
              // do filter stuff..
            } else {
              // return all 
            }
       };
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have no idea how to run filter limitTo: inside 

`if(categories.$loaded()) {
              $filter('limitTo')(elms, 3);
            } `

Something in this direction?

Comment: can you send it in a jsfiddle? I'll help you then)